# What is the difference between "Include Directories" and "Additional Include Directories"

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, compilation

In configuration properties of my project, under the "VC++ directories" there is an entry for "Include Directories". But under "C/C++" option, there is another entry called "Additional Include Directories". Same thing happens with library directories.

What are the difference between these two entries?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 56, accepted):

This is awkwardness that got introduced in VS2010.  The VC++ Directories settings used to be located in Tools + Options, Projects and Solutions, VC++ Directories.  Global settings that applied to every project that was built on the machine.  It is still there but points out that you should now change it in your project settings.  A side-effect of the build engine overhaul in VS2010, enabling building with msbuild.  Removing the per-project settings would have been logical but that would break too many existing projects.

As such, it is probably best to treat the VC++ Directories settings as the machine default.  It is automatically preset by the VS installer.  Tinker with it only if you need an unusual directory search order, putting the custom locations last.  Very unusual to do so.

It does work however.  And it did get taken advantage of eventually.  Empowering the Platform Toolset setting in VS2012 and up.  Different compiler, different linker, different #include directories, different linker search path.  Modified with just one setting, nice.

Comment: Hmmm ... It *is* true that the gloabl options are saved under this - but this is the property sheet `Microsoft.Cpp.Win32.user` and only this. If you edit the "VC++ Directories" entry when having the project active or another property sheet, then the change will be persisted in the `.vcxproj`file or in the respective `.props` file and will not be global or user-wide at all.

Answer (score 33):

## CONFIGURING INCLUDE PATHS

#### VC++ Directories: Include Directories

- this value is inherited from the `INCLUDE` *Windows* environment variable which is defined outside of *Visual Studio*

  - environment variables can be: global to the computer or have user level scope
  - The `INCLUDE` and `LIB` environment variables are created when the *Microsoft Windows SDK* is installed with *Visual Studio*.

#### C/C++: Additional Include Directories

- is a project level setting... you will have to define this value for every project in your solution
- this value can be persisted to source control

## ADDITIONAL NOTES

#### Which one should I use?

The decision to use *Include Directories* or *Additional Include Directories* will depend on your organization's development process.  In my opinion, it is more important:

- that you are able to consistently and reliably re-create the development environment (think: handing off source code to another developer)
- for developers within an organization use a consistent approach

#### A Note About Macros

- The C++ project configuration *macros* (not to be confused with C++ pre-processor `#define` directive) inherit content from different sources. Macros like...

  - `$(Include)` inherit their values from *Windows* environment variables
  - `$(OutDir)` inherit their values from *Visual Studio* IDE

## REFERENCES

- [Environment Variables (general introduction)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable#Windows)
- [How to set the path and environment variables in Windows](http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm)

Answer (score 30):

The [Include Directories](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t9az1d21%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) corresponds to the environment variable `INCLUDE`.

> Directory settings displayed in the window are the directories that
>   Visual Studio will search for include files referred to in your source
>   code files. Corresponds to environment variable INCLUDE.

While the [Additional Include Directories](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/73f9s62w%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) are passed via a command line argument (i.e. the `\I` option).

Answer (score 10):

[What is the difference between #include <filename> and #include "filename"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21593/what-is-the-difference-between-include-filename-and-include-filename)

"Include Directories" -> `#include <header>`

"Additional Include Directories" -> `#include "header"`