# Additional include directories in VS2010 for an "empty C++" project

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I am creating a sample project (a Hello, World!) with [libevent](http://libevent.org/).

*(Just for note: This question has got nothing to do with libevent but with Visual Studio. :-))*

I compiled the library separately outside but under Visual Studio environment.

Wanted to test with a sample code and I started with creating a new project in VS2010.
I selected `Visual C++ --> General --> Empty Project`.

When I selected the project properties to add the 'additional include directories' I do not find
`C/C++` node where it is usually added. 
This is how it looks:
[image: Additional include directories in VS2010 for an empty C++ project]

However, when I select `Visual C++ --> Win32 --> Win32 Console Application` I will be able to see the `C/C++` node and add the additional include directories.

I read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6883276/what-is-the-difference-between-include-directories-and-additional-include-dir) and understood I can add the required directories in `VC++ Directories --> Include Directories`. But yet it's not so very advisable to change the default setting.

Is there any other way I can add additional include directories without selecting the `C++ --> Win32 --> Win32 Console Application` project? Just want to know.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to have at least one .cpp file added to the project to be able to see the C/C++ settings.  Otherwise, being an empty project, VS does not know what language you are using

Answer (score 1):

You have to have a C++ project. It doesn't need to be a console application; you could also create a static library (.lib) or dynamic library (.dll).