# Visual Studio 2010 - how do I speed loading of large solution?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, intellisense

The solution I typically work with contains a couple of dozen projects. When I load this solution the status line displays something like "searching #includes for additional files", with a counting up well over one thousand. This can take 15-30 seconds (machine has quad core i7, 8G RAM and SSD, Windows 7 Pro, SP1). It the spends another 15 seconds or so "updating intellisense". In spite of all this preparation, if I right-click on a function or method and select Go To Definition, I'll frequently get a dialog box with "Please wait". This can take 10-15 seconds, though usually after the first few times, the search is instant. Others working on this solution (all are local copies managed by git and Cmake, no shared disk or anything) have the same experience.

Are there settings or something that will remove or lessen these problems. Or is this what happens when a solution gets to this size?

Thanks

Comment: I'm afraid, there's not much you can do, other than installing Visual Studio 6. Microsoft keep improving loading speeds with each new release of Visual Studio, but cannot seem to get down to an acceptable delay, even if run on a mid-range to high-end machine, like yours.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do much about it.  I've worked on large solutions on Quad Code i7 with 16/32 GB RAM on Win7/XP.  They tend to load slow, build slow, start slow...

I do not recall messages about Additional Includes though. 
Check out these pages, they may help:

[msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/73f9s62w.aspx),

[SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6883276/what-is-the-difference-between-include-directories-and-additional-include-dir)

Tinkering with settings might help, but be careful, as sometimes they lead to big problems and you have to restart your project.