# dlib: how to set #include search path in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, include-path, dlib

I am currently trying to set up dlib on my computer for machine learning purposes.

I have the latest version of Visual Studio Community and the instruction on the project page http://dlib.net/compile.html states

> All you need to do is create an empty console project. Then add dlib/all/source.cpp to it and add the folder containing the dlib folder to the #include search path. Then you can compile any example program by adding it to your project.

I did add the source.cpp file to my project. However, I cant figure out how to add the folder to the #include search path.

Would somebody be so kind and enlighten me please?

Thanks in advance

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6883276/what-is-the-difference-between-include-directories-and-additional-include-dir. Briefly, project properties -> C/C++ -> Additional Include Directories

Comment: thank you! The advise "and add the folder containing the dlib folder to the #include search path" is wrong though. You have to add the flder itself and not the coprising folder as is issued on a number of occasions on the dlib wegpage

Comment: Right. You actually have to add the folder that contains the header files. This path gets passed to the compiler as an argument, and the compiler will search there for any header files you include. Technically, I suppose, you could pass `C:\dev\dlib` and then `#include "include/header.h"`, though. Perhaps their samples show something like that?

Comment: thanks a ton. And that is really all I have to do to work with dlib to its full extend is it?