# How to add a library, header file in Visual studio 2015

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, eigen

I am fairly new to Visual Studio. There is this open source linear solver called [Eigen](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/GettingStarted.html). I have currently downloaded the zip file containing all the header file according to the documentation I don't need to use Cmake or install or anything. I just need to make sure that the compiler has access to the Eigen header files. The documentation gives me different ways of doing this if I use gcc but I am using Visual Studio 2015. I have extracted the zip file and I know the location of the header file that I plan to use but I am having trouble doing that on Visual Studio. Any help is appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: You will have to set the include path in the project options accordingly.

Comment: This is basically the same step as the linked example. Instead of the `-I pathToInclude` you set the path in "Additional Include Directories" in Visual Studio.

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24715864/problems-importing-libraries-to-my-c-project-how-to-fix-this) helps you to understand better.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Right click on the project you want to modify
- Choose VC++ directories
- Then Modify the include directories and update it

Answer (score 1):

Actually it's better to add that to `C/C++ -> Include Directories`, the difference is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6883276/what-is-the-difference-between-include-directories-and-additional-include-dir), you can also use the screenshots from there.