# How to make Visual Studio 2017 see my .h file using angle brackets?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017

I have a Visual Studio 2017 solution and C++ project with one source file called Source.cpp. Inside Source.cpp I have `#include <FL/Fl.H>` which appears red underlined because Visual Studio cannot find it.

On my file system, I have verified that the file `c:\fltk\include\FL\Fl.H` exists, and I right clicked my project and added the directory `c:\fltk\include` into the project `Include Directories`.

Hopefully this picture can explain my frustration
[image: VS2017 not finding the file]

How can I get Visual Studio 2017 to include the file?

Comment: If any downvoters could please leave a comment about what needs improvement I will edit the question

Comment: Why do you want to use angle brackets?

Comment: See [What is the difference between #include <filename> and #include “filename”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21593/what-is-the-difference-between-include-filename-and-include-filename)

Comment: @PeterWood FLTK is a GUI toolkit library. I would rather not copy the header files directly into my project, but rather have them live on my system so that they can better be shared across projects. I believe this is also the standard use case for angle bracket includes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer has to do with the **Solution Platform** and the **Solution Configuration**

As you can see in the screenshot, the property pages are set to edit **Configuration: Release** and **Platform: x64** which happened to be different from my "Active Solution Platform" and "Active solution configuration" which was set to **Debug** and **x86** respectively. See the screenshot below.

[image: active solution and platform]

When I switched to **Configuration: All Configurations** and **Platform: All Platforms** and then added the include folder, everything worked! See the screenshot below.
[image]

Also note I changed from using the **VC++ Directories** option group to the **C/C++** option group. I haven't quite understood what the difference is although there are some explanations here [What is the difference between "Include Directories" and "Additional Include Directories"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6883276/what-is-the-difference-between-include-directories-and-additional-include-dir)

I'm still unclear why this question got downvoted, but I think this answer will probably be useful to other Visual Studio newbies who made the same mistake I did.