# Visual Studio 2017 only include my files using #include "File" but failed with #include <file>

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I am building a **C** project that uses some header files of mines. I put these files in a folder and add that path in **Project Properties-->C/C++-->General-->Additional Include Directories**. When I use `#include "myfile.h"`, it works fine. But when I use `#include <myfile.h>`, it says Can not open include file. Thanks

Comment: That is entirely normal.  The include path for angle bracketed files is set by Project > Properties > VC++ Directories > "Include Directories".  It should be reserved for compiler and OS headers.

Comment: It means, I can not use angle bracket in my case? As I have to change everywhere in my project because there are a lot. I thought there must be some flag that resolves this issue.

Comment: Have you had a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47492634/how-to-make-visual-studio-2017-see-my-h-file-using-angle-brackets?rq=1) ?

Comment: It should work just fine. Just double-checked with a new VS solution. What @VishaalShankar implies: Have you checked that you build the same configuration (Platform/Debug/Release) that you have set the include directories for?

Comment: yes I checked the configuration. I changed it to "double quoted" instead of angle bracket.