# Eigen program failing to compile from Visual Studio, but compilation succeeds from the command-line

Tags: c++, visual-studio, eigen

I created a new project in Visual Studio 2015 that consists of just one C++ file "test.cpp" that uses Eigen. I installed Eigen in the "C:\eigen" directory. When I tried to build the solution from within Visual Studio it failed because it couldn't find the Eigen header files, even though I added the "C:\eigen" directory to the include directories of the project. This was the error I got:

```
Cannot open include file: 'Eigen/Dense': No such file or directory
```

However when I opened the "Developer Command Prompt for VS2015", went to the directory containing the "test.cpp" file, and ran the command:

```
cl test.cpp -I "C:\eigen"
```

it succeeded. Why would the compilation fail from within Visual Studio but succeed from the command line?

Here is how I added the Eigen library to my Visual Studio Include Directories:

[image]

Comment: Always post any errors you get *verbatim*, *in* the question.

Comment: ***even though I added the "C:\eigen" directory to the include directories of the project.*** Maybe you did not add it correctly or you did not add it to all configurations.

Comment: I updated my question with the error I was getting, and a screenshot of my VS project properties showing how I added the include directory.

Comment: Sounds like the installation of Eigen (which I'm not familiar with) may depend on some things in your environment that aren't there. I bet rebooting your PC would solve the problem (or simply restarting VS). Have you tried this?

Comment: I tried rebooting and it didn't help. Eigen is just a collection of header files, so it doesn't need to be installed really.

Comment: There's a [difference between `-I` and `Include Directories`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6883392/3426025) have you tried the `Additional Include Directories` under C++/General? And please add the erroneous build output to your question.

Comment: I tried adding "C:\eigen" to `Additional Include Directories` and it still fails to compile in VS. The error I mentioned in the question is the compile error I get.

Comment: The only way you'll get to the bottom of your issue is to understand the build output. [Cranking up the verbosity](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/msbuild/2005/09/28/cranking-up-the-build-verbosity-in-the-ide/) should help with that.

Comment: By turning on the detailed build log I was able to see that the `C:\eigen` directory was not being added to the `INCLUDE` environment variable at all, and figured out it was because the configuration and build platforms were different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that I configured the project for the x64 platform, but was building for the x86 platform. After I made the change to build for the x64 platform the build succeeded.